# Laravel fail to delete if only 1 record left

Tags: laravel, delete-row, sweetalert

I bump into this problem. i have delete button and if working just fine if there is more than 1 record.

But if there is only 1 record left, it wont deleting. So, i cant delete all the row and i will always have 1 record left.
I implemented softdelete in my model.

And it doesn give any error, it just do nothing after i confirm deletion

My delete button code

```
<button id="delete" data-title="{{ $vw_tracing_c19d->nama }}" type="button"
    class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="{{ route('tracing-record.destroy', $vw_tracing_c19d->id) }}"
    style="margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
    <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete zmdi-hc-fw" style="color: #fff; font-size: 1.5em;"></i>
    Delete
</button>

<form method="post" id="deleteForm">
    @csrf
    @method("DELETE")
    <input type="submit" value="" style="display:none;">
</form>


@push('script')
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // Sweetalert Confirm
        $('button#delete').on('click', function (event) {

            event.preventDefault();
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            var title = $(this).data('title');

            swal({
                title: "Yakin Akan hapus " + title + " ?",
                text: "Data akan hilang dari database !!!",
                icon: "warning",
                dangerMode: true,
                buttons:{
                    cancel: {
                        visible: true,
                        text : 'Batal',
                        // className : 'btn btn-warning'
                        className : 'btn btn-success'
                    },
                    confirm: {
                        text : 'Hapus',
                        className: 'btn btn-danger'
                    }
                }
            })
                .then((willDelete) => {
                    if (willDelete) {
                        document.getElementById('deleteForm').action = href;
                        document.getElementById('deleteForm').submit();
                        swal("Data " + title + " berhasil dihapus!", {
                            icon: "success",
                        });
                    } else {
                        swal("Batal", "Data tidak dihapus", "error");
                    }
                });
        });
</script>
@endpush
```

my model

```
class TracingRecordDt extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'tracing_c19d';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    protected $dates = [
        'deleted_at',
    ];


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

My controller

```
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        dd('test'); //doesn't even run, if 1 record left 

        $tracing_recorddts = TracingRecordDt::findOrFail($id);
        $tracing_recorddts->delete();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

And my route

```
    Route::resource('tracing-record', 'TracingRecordController');
```

Comment: Can you print out error message? I'm guessing that record might have a foreign key somewhere that prevents it from deleting

Comment: @AnuratChapanond he is using soft delete. so, there shouldn't be any issue with foreign keys.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks @SKR

Comment: why are you using redirect back @heru-handoko ? it will send error response. you can return ```redirect()->route('route.name')```

Comment: @skr because if im using route.name i need to pass some params. and as i mentioned in my post, it works well if there is more than 1 records

Comment: @HeruHandoko because we don't know what are the output of the statements, we cant give any solution for it. can you ````dd()```` the ````$tracing_recorddts```` and ````$tracing_recorddts->delete()```` with us? like ````dd($tracing_recorddts, $tracing_recorddts->delete());```` screenshots..

Comment: @SKR no error is given. if i dd in my destroy function, it wont give anything. i presume it doesnt even call the destroy function

Comment: so i think the problem lies in my view, somewhere in my button or my script

Comment: are you calling it from AJAX ? then why are you returning redirect response ? you can return true or false. redirect response may be not handled properly in JS

Comment: can you add a console.log in the success and error callback of ajax ? with console log, you can check the API call response preview in networking tab. add a ````dd()```` and the response will be printed in it.